# Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array - Google Charts

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, pygooglechart

**Controller Code : **

```
           $http({method: 'GET',
              url: '/proj_prof_table',
              params: {id: id}
            }).success(function(response) 
          {

            $scope.data = response;

            $scope.emp_id = [];
            $scope.emp_name = [];
            $scope.billing_status = [];
            $scope.mgr = [];
            $scope.mgr_id = [];
            $scope.stdt = [];
            for(i in $scope.data)
                {
                    $scope.emp_id.push($scope.data[i].Emp_ID);
                    $scope.emp_name.push($scope.data[i].Emp_Name);
                    $scope.billing_status.push($scope.data[i].Billing_Status);
                    $scope.mgr.push($scope.data[i].Manager);
                    $scope.mgr_id.push($scope.data[i].Mgr_ID);
                    $scope.stdt.push($scope.data[i].Start_Date);
                }
          });
        // Get client timeline 
         // Prepare Data 
     $http({method: 'GET',
              url: '/proj_prof_client_timeline',
              params: {id: clid}
            }).success(function(response) 
          {

            $scope.data = response;
            alert($scope.data);
            $scope.project = [];
            $scope.stdt = [];
            $scope.endt = [];
            $scope.x = [];
            for(i in $scope.data)
                {
                    $scope.x[i] = [];
                    $scope.x[i].push($scope.data[i].Proj_Name);
                    $scope.x[i].push($scope.data[i].Start_Date);
                    $scope.x[i].push($scope.data[i].End_Date);
                }

                alert($scope.x[0]);
          });

       drawChart($scope.x);

 }


  //time line chart
  google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['timeline']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
  function drawChart(param) {


    //Chart code
    var container = document.getElementById('timeline');
    var chart = new google.visualization.Timeline(container);
    var dataTable = new google.visualization.DataTable();

    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'string', id: 'Projects' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'Start' });
    dataTable.addColumn({ type: 'date', id: 'End' });
    dataTable.addRows(param);

    chart.draw(dataTable);
  }
```

the code above throws "Argument given to addRows must be either a number or an array"

besides $scope.x being an 2D array

Is there anyother way in which i could define $scope.x as a [[ele,ele,ele],[ele,ele,ele],[ele,ele,ele]] array to pass it as an parameter to addrows()

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
 $scope.emplist = [
                   {empname:'samudrala',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 450'},
                   {empname:'soujanya',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 451'},
                   {empname:'jai',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 455'},
               
                   {empname:'Raamu',empsalary:'4.5 - pam',empid:'Emp - 459'}
                   ];
  $scope.addItem = function(){
  $scope.emplist.push({'empname':$scope.empname,'empsalary':$scope.empsalary,'empid':$scope.empid});
  $scope.empname = '';
  $scope.empsalary = '';
  $scope.empid = '';
 }
  $scope.remItem = function(item){
    $scope.emplist.splice(item,1);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
<table style="width:100%;">
<tr height="25" style=" background: #99ff00;">
<th width="5%"></th>
<th width="40%">EMP Name</th>
<th width="30%">EMP Salary</th>
<th width="">EMP ID</th>
<th width=""></th>
</tr>
<tr height="25" ng-repeat="x in emplist">
<td style="text-align: center;">{{$index}}</td>

<td style="text-align: center; ">{{x.empname}}</td>

<td style="text-align: center;">{{x.empsalary}}</td>

<td style="text-align: center;">{{x.empid}}</td>

<td style="text-align: center;"><button ng-click="remItem($index);" style="background:#00ffff; border:0px;">&times; Remove</button></td>

</tr>
<tr height="25">
<td><button ng-click="addItem();" style="background: #00ffff; border:0px; width:100%; height:100%;">Add</button></td>
<td style="padding:2px;"><input type="text" ng-model="empname" style="width:100%;" ></td>
<td style="padding:2px;"><input type="text" ng-model="empsalary" style="width:100%;" ></td>
<td style="padding:2px;"><input type="text" ng-model="empid" style="width:100%;" ></td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```